# Find all relations on A that are both reflexive and antisymmetric

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, relations

This is the only question on my homework that still gives me a headache, I have to find out how many relations there are on $A = \{1,2,3,...,7\}$ that are both reflexive and antisymmetric.
So far all I've gotten is the following:

For antisymmetry alone, there are $7$ distinct pairs $(a,a)$ and $21$ distinct pairs $(a,b)$ with $a < b$.
The pairs $(a,a)$ are either contained within the relation or not, while the pairs $(a,b)$ can be contained, not be contained, or be inversed as $(b,a)$. This results in $2^7 \times 3^{21}$ antisymmetric possible relations, ignoring the fact that the relation should also be reflexive.

However, since both criteria need to be met, I need to find a way to incorporate the reflexive argument as well. This implies that if $(a,b)$ is contained, there is also a corresponding $(a,a)$, but I don't see any way to continue from here.

In retrospect, I feel as though my approach wasn't great to begin with, but I am now at a point where I have absolutely no idea what else to do, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, good question! Here is a tutorial on how to format math equations on this site: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I think this answer below is complete. If it doesn't answer your question, you are working in some non-standard setting of maths - so I suggest you to edit your question to include *your* definitions of the terms *"relation", "reflexive", "anti-symmetric"* and explain which part of the answer confuses you

Comment: Reflexivity means simply that the relation holds between any element and itself, in other words that the entire diagonal is contained in the graph of the relation. Apart from failing to use this, which would replace your factor $2^7$ by $1$ (no choice on the diagonal), your analysis is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflexivity means that for each $a$, you have to include the pair $(a,a)$ into relation. We have no freedom here. So, all the pairs $(1,1)$, ..., $(7,7)$ must be included in any such relation.

Now go on to antisymmetry property. By definition, it means that **if** both pairs $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ are included, **then** $a=b$. Let's reformulate that using contraposition: **if** $a \neq b$, **then** at least one of pairs $(a,b)$ or $(b,a)$ must **not** be included (may be both of them).

So, for each (unordered) pair $\{a,b\}$ where $a \neq b$, we have exactly 3 opportunities:

1. include only $(a,b)$ but not $(b,a)$;
2. include only $(b,a)$ but not $(a,b)$;
3. include none of them.

For each such pair, we can choose one of these opportunities independently from choices for other pairs. We have in total $\frac{7 \cdot 6}{2}=21$ such pairs, and so in total we have $3^{21}$ possibilities.

Note once again that for pairs of kind $(a,a)$ we have no choice, they all must be included. And this does not affect our choices for pairs $(a,b)$ with $a\neq b$.

So, the answer is $3^{21}$.